# Binance WebSocket API

Tags: websocket, cryptography, binance

how can I get live stream from binance web-socket. anyone know about that?

I tried his documentation but I can not understand properly
https://github.com/binance/binance-spot-api-docs/blob/master/web-socket-streams.md#subscribe-to-a-stream
above his documentation link

Answer (score 0):

try this documentation
[MarketStream](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#websocket-market-streams)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this, one of them is the following example:

```js
const binanceSocket = new WebSocket("wss://stream.binance.com:9443/ws/!miniTicker@arr");

binanceSocket.onmessage = function (event) {
    const messageObject = JSON.parse(event.data);
    $("." + messageObject[0].s).html(messageObject[0].c);

    messageObject.forEach(function (item, index) {
        if (item.s === 'BTCUSDT') {
            let btcValue = parseFloat(item.c);
            $("#btcValue").html("BTC: $" + btcValue.toFixed(2));
        }
    });
}
```